# Curl request from docker container to host timeout

Tags: curl, nginx, docker, docker-network

Im encountering an issue with docker which I believe is due to a gap in my knowledge about docker networking.

I have a docker image running nginx and php. The necessary ports are exposed. Here is a simplified command I have been using to run the image.

`docker run --name php-app -p 80:80 php-app`

The issue is that for installation setup, the php application curls to itself using the host machines public IP.

As an example,
`curl http://105.15.25.120/phpsetup.php?setup`

This IP seems to be unreachable from inside the container, as curl times out

```
curl -vvv 105.15.25.120
About to connect() to 105.15.25.120 port 80 (#0)
Trying 105.15.25.120...
Connection timed out
Failed connect to 105.15.25.120:80; Connection timed out
Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed connect to 105.15.25.120:80; Connection timed out
```

I can successfully curl to other IP's from inside the container, just not the host's.

Using curl from the host machine works fine, and does not result in any strange behaviour.

For simplicity and testing, I have reproduced the behaviour with the official nginx image, to help conclude that it's not an issue with my own image.

`docker run --name some-nginx -v /some/content:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro -p 80:80`

From my research, it seems to be a routing issue? Not sure.

Comment: Your host may have firewall rules that prohibit connections from inside the Docker container.  Review in particular the rules in the `INPUT` chain of the `filter` table.

Comment: How do you know the host machine's IP address from inside the container? Do you provide it to the container when starting the container?

Comment: Yeah, through an ENV variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the container should not curl the host. it should curl itself, as it is hosting the content you wish to curl.

`curl http://127.0.0.1/phpsetup.php?setup`

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is this by design may I ask?

Comment: it's a best practice. the container should not care about the host or anything in / on / about the host, but should run self-contained. the exception for this is what the `docker run` command provides to the container (data volumes, environment vars, and other bits)

Comment: Is there a way to allow the curl to the host IP still? I understand it's not great but it covers edge cases in the php application.